# Logstash/not logstash for kafka-elasticsearch integration?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, apache-kafka

I read that elasticsearch rivers/river plugins are deprecated. So we cannot directly have elasticsearch-kafka integration. If we want to do this then we need to have some java(or any language) layer in between that puts the data from kafka to elastic search using its apis.

On the other hand – if we have kafka-logstash-elasticsearch – that we get rid of the above middle layer and achieve that through logstash with just configuration. But I am not sure if having logstash in between is an overhead or not?

And is my undertsanding right?
Thanks in advance for the inputs.

Regards,
Priya

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite general. It would be good to understand your architecture, its purpose and assumptions you made.

Kafka, as it is stated in its documentation, is a massively scalable publish-subscribe messaging system. My assumption would be that you use it to as a data broker in your architecture.

Elasticsearch on the other hand, is a search engine, hence I assume that you use it as a data access/searching/aggregation layer.

These two separate systems require connectors to create a proper data-pipeline. That's where Logstash comes in. It allows you to create data streaming connection between, in your case, Kafka and Elasticsearch. It also allows you to mutate the data on the fly, depending on your needs.

Ideally, Kafka uses raw data events. Elasticsearch stores documents which are useful to your data consumers (web or mobile application, other systems etc.), so can be quite different to the raw data format. If you need to modify the data between its raw form, and ES document, that's where Logstash might be handy (see [filters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/filter-plugins.html) stage).

Another approach could be to use Kafka Connectors, building custom tools e.g. based on Kafka Streams or Consumers, but it really depends on the concepts of your architecture - purpose, stack, data requirements and more.